# my application crash (with assertion) after the splash screen at BOTH of my devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have got the following logcat result after trying to build and run my app from Unity 3.5.6.
    I have no problem deploying two simple apps like "touch phase" and "roll-a-ball" from the Unity web.
    Could anybody kindly shed me some light on this issue??

```
BTW, I have tried the check list here.
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/TroubleShooting.html#AndroidTroubleShooting

My device OSes are Android 2.2 and 2.3.2.  And I have tried on both my MacOS and WinXP.
Your help will be greatly appreciated!!! mOm

SWD


======== start
I/dalvikvm( 1587): Could not find method android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.setPreserveEGLContext OnPause, referenced from method com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a
W/dalvikvm( 1587): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 194: Landroid/opengl/GLSurfaceView;.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause (Z)V
D/dalvikvm( 1587): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x006c
D/dalvikvm( 280): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 198K, 52% free 2959K/6087K, external 2914K/2928K, paused 153ms
I/dalvikvm( 1587): Could not find method android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.setPreserveEGLContext OnPause, referenced from method com.unity3d.player.aa.run
W/dalvikvm( 1587): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 194: Landroid/opengl/GLSurfaceView;.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause (Z)V
D/dalvikvm( 1587): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000f
I/dalvikvm( 1587): Could not find method android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.setPreserveEGLContext OnPause, referenced from method com.unity3d.player.aa.run
W/dalvikvm( 1587): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 194: Landroid/opengl/GLSurfaceView;.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause (Z)V


.....


D/Unity ( 1587): Multi-casting "[IP] 0.0.0.0 [Port] 55426 [Flags] 2 [Guid] 2017919413 [EditorId] 200989420 [Version] 1048832 [Id] AndroidPlayer(Sony_Ericsson_R800a:0.0.0.0) [Debug] 0" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
F/mono ( 1587): * Assertion at threads.c:4189, condition `offset' not met
D/Unity ( 1587): InitializeMonoFromMain OK (3007ff00)
D/Unity ( 1587): PlayerConnection::Initialize
D/Unity ( 1587): PlayerInitEngineNoGraphics OK
D/Unity ( 1587): Renderer: Adreno 205
D/Unity ( 1587): Vendor: Qualcomm
D/Unity ( 1587): Version: OpenGL ES 2.0 1403843


....

(stack trace)
========= end
```

Comment: Don't know much about unity export, but do they give you an option to build for lower targets? That function `setPreserveEGLContext` is only available in Api 11+ (Honeycomb+). I'm not sure why it would be using it unless Unity doesn't support GBread.

Comment: Good point!  I chose Api 8 for the minimum requirement when I export...  Unity is supposed to support Api 8+...